# Merge the data relating to each unique Object in a List and transform them into a List of another Type using Streams

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have a list of Beans  (*List 1*)  and I want to convert it to another list (*List 2*).

I've managed to achieve that. But I have the impression it made it too complicated : pick out the `id`'s + *loop* + *stream* again.

My question is : is it possible to make it simpler ?

*Sample data - List1:*

```
[Customer [id=1, name=jon, carType=fiat, color=black], 
 Customer [id=2, name=din, carType=ford, color=yellow], 
 Customer [id=1, name=jon, carType=benz, color=white], 
 Customer [id=1, name=jon, carType=volvo, color=red], 
 Customer [id=3, name=fin, carType=volvo, color=black], 
 Customer [id=3, name=fin, carType=fiat, color=green], 
 Customer [id=4, name=lara, carType=bmw, color=red], 
 Customer [id=5, name=tina, carType=toyota, color=white], 
 Customer [id=5, name=tina, carType=fiat, color=yelow], 
 Customer [id=6, name=bogi, carType=benz, color=black]]
```

*Sample data - List2:*

```
ImprovedCustomer [id=1, name=jon, cars=[Car [carType=fiat, color=black], Car [carType=benz, color=white], Car [carType=volvo, color=red]]]
ImprovedCustomer [id=2, name=din, cars=[Car [carType=ford, color=yellow]]]
ImprovedCustomer [id=3, name=fin, cars=[Car [carType=volvo, color=black], Car [carType=fiat, color=green]]]
ImprovedCustomer [id=4, name=lara, cars=[Car [carType=bmw, color=red]]]
ImprovedCustomer [id=5, name=tina, cars=[Car [carType=toyota, color=white], Car [carType=fiat, color=yelow]]]
ImprovedCustomer [id=6, name=bogi, cars=[Car [carType=benz, color=black]]]
```

*My code:*

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Customer(1, "jon", "fiat", "black"));
        list.add(new Customer(2, "din", "ford", "yellow"));
        list.add(new Customer(1, "jon", "benz", "white"));
        list.add(new Customer(1, "jon", "volvo", "red"));
        list.add(new Customer(3, "fin", "volvo", "black"));
        list.add(new Customer(3, "fin", "fiat", "green"));
        list.add(new Customer(4, "lara", "bmw", "red"));
        list.add(new Customer(5, "tina", "toyota", "white"));
        list.add(new Customer(5, "tina", "fiat", "yelow"));
        list.add(new Customer(6, "bogi", "benz", "black"));

        List<Integer> ids = list.stream().map(Customer::getId).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<ImprovedCustomer> ImprovedCustomers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int id : ids) {
            ImprovedCustomer improvedCustomer = new ImprovedCustomer(id);
            List<Car> collect = list.stream().filter(a -> a.getId().equals(id)).map(a -> {
                if (improvedCustomer.getName() == null) {
                    improvedCustomer.setName(a.getName());
                }
                return new Car(a.getCarType(), a.getColor());
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

            improvedCustomer.setCars(collect);
            ImprovedCustomers.add(improvedCustomer);
        }
    }
}

class Customer {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String carType;
    private String color;

    public Customer(Integer id, String name, String carType, String color) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.carType = carType;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCarType() {
        return carType;
    }

    public void setCarType(String carType) {
        this.carType = carType;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}

class Car {

    private String carType;
    private String color;

    public Car(String carType, String color) {
        super();
        this.carType = carType;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getCarType() {
        return carType;
    }

    public void setCarType(String carType) {
        this.carType = carType;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}

class ImprovedCustomer {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private List<Car> cars;

    public ImprovedCustomer() {
        super();
    }

    public ImprovedCustomer(Integer id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ImprovedCustomer(Integer id, String name, List<Car> cars) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy`.

Comment: You should make `Customer` class have `Car` field rather than duplicate that information. You should also implement `equals` (and `hashcode`) so that the ID and name field are known to be the same customer. **Then**, you can group them and `aggregate` the CarType fields into a list

Comment: If your code works, but you are looking for possible improvements (not only in terms of performance) then you can consider asking it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution performs an iteration over the list of *customers* for every unique `id`.

As *@Johannes Kuhn* has pointed out in the comments, you can eliminate redundant iterations by making use of the *collector* [`groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)). With this *collector*, we can map each *customer* with unique `id` to a *list of cars* in a single iteration.

And then construct a list of `ImprovedCustomer` objects based on every entry of the map generated by `groupingBy()`.

*Note: that in order to use this approach, either `Customer` class should implement `equals/hashCode` contract based on the `id` and `name` properties, or we need to use an auxiliary record (or class) that would wrap a `Customer` object. For simplicity, I'll assume that we can rely on the `Customer` class `equals/hashCode` implementations.*

So, in the code below as *classifier* function I've applied `Function.identity()` (i.e. a *key* would be a *customer* itself) and as *downstream collector* a combination of *collectors* `mapping()` and `toList()`, which transforms every *customer* into a `Car` object, and collect the *cars* mapped to the same customer into a list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Customer> customers = // initializing the list of customers

    List<ImprovedCustomer> improvedCustomers = customers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Function.identity(),
            Collectors.mapping(cust -> new Car(cust.getCarType(), cust.getColor()),
                Collectors.toList())
        ))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new ImprovedCustomer(entry.getKey().getId(), entry.getKey().getName(), entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```